# Is GET /entry/new considered best practice for displaying the input form for creating a new resource?

Tags: rest

Consider a Resource named *Entry*, with endpoints:

- `GET /entries` (show all entries)
- `GET /entries/<x>` (show entry x)
- `POST /entries` (create new entry)
- `PUT /entries/<x>` (change an existing entry x)
- `DELETE /entries/<x>` (delete an existing entry x)

These I'm sure of. But how about:

- `GET /entries/new` (show input form for creation of new entry)
- `GET /entries/<x>/edit`  (show input form for update of existing entry)

Are these patterns considered best practice as well? If not, which are?

Comment: What is the intended use? Web services only? A website (human clients)? Both a web service and website? I'm guessing it is a website (as you mention forms), no?

Comment: Yeah `GET /entries/new` would be for an admin-frontend. And together with `GET /entries/<x>/edit` would be the only endpoints that spit out HTML. The rest returns JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `GET /entries` (show all entries)
- `GET /entries/<x>` (show entry x)
- `POST /entries` (create new entry)
- `PUT /entries/<x>` (change an existing entry x)
- `DELETE /entries/<x>` (delete an existing entry x)

**Are all OK**, as you expected.

- `GET /entries/new` (show input form for creation of new entry)
- `GET /entries/<x>/edit`  (show input form for update of existing entry)

If you want to keep it simple, **these two are OK as well** (they are common, used by big players and frameworks, respect RESTful principles and are somewhat of a standard).

#### Sources/samples:

- [Microformats wiki](http://microformats.org/wiki/rest/urls) - some good info here, with suggestions on how to work around browser method limitations
- Stack Exchange: `/questions/ask` (instead of `/new`) to display the create form; `/questions/id/slugified-title` to view; `/post/<x>/edit` to display the edit form.
- GitHub's issues: `/project/issues`; `/project/issues/new`; `/project/issues/<x>`; they don't have an `/edit` URL, as all editing is done in-place via JS.
- The standard followed by Rails: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions

### Long story

To achieve the scalability and loose coupling of a go RESTful architecture, it helps to think of your application in terms of resources. So every URL should be pointing to a different resource. So:

`GET /entries/<x>` is OK because it would return the resource "entry of identity `<x>`".

Now, the `GET /entries/new` is a resource as well, but more of a "utility" one. It is just that the resource presented by this address is a form (a document explaining how to create entries - could be a WADL instead of a form as well).

#### The `/edit` possibilities

The `GET /entries/<x>/edit`, if you want, is the one we could get by without. As we know, the `GET` returns a representation of the current state of a resource, not (necessarily) the resource. This way, if a resource is (currently) editable, the GET URL would return it in an editable fashion, if not, then it would be read-only (thus no need for an `/edit` resource).

Another way of achieving this is having `GET entries/<x>` return JSON of HTML content based on the `Accept` header. This way, if the `Accept` had `text/html`, the page returned would be a form containing the all the info (again, if the resource was in an editable state, the form would be editable. If not, then it would be read-only).

Now I see this may not be optimal, as you may not want to display the form everytime (on `GET /entries/<x>`). If this is the case, you have almost two resources:

- `GET /entries/<x>` - the entry
- `GET /entries/<x>/edit` - This "resource" would be a file describing what sort of HTTP request the client must make if it wants to edit an entry state. In your case it is a form (telling the client how to send or simulate a PUT request), but could be a short WADL file as well.